# glClearBufferData - Usage Example?

Tags: c++, opengl

```
void glClearBufferData(GLenum target, GLenum internalformat, GLenum format, 
      GLenum type, const void* data);
```

I'm not quite sure how to use this method properly. More specifically the *internalformat* and *format* parameters. The [official documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClearBufferData.xml) is very vague about what these are, and I'm having trouble finding a list of available targets for these. Are these set targets, or do I need to just to pass a size for the data or something? I also couldn't find any usage examples of this function online... could anyone provide me with one, or perhaps a list of targets?

Comment: why are you trying to clear your buffer data? your `target` is your buffer var

Comment: Is there something that [the OpenGL wiki article on buffer objects doesn't cover?](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#Clearing) It assumes that you know how [OpenGL objects work](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Object).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **target** is the target to which the destination buffer is bound.
- **internalFormat** must be set to one of the format tokens given by openGL
- **format and type** specify the format and type of the source data.
- **data** is the converted data passed to the buffer

Reference: http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/clear_buffer_object.txt

You can find a list of some internal formats here: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml

though i cannot seem to find table 3.15 that the text references.

EXAMPLE:
[image]

You can find this article [here](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://education.siggraph.org/media/conference/S2012_Materials/ComputeShader_1pp.pdf)

Comment: That table was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.